# Remove android gridview scroll-end highlight

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, highlight

When scrolling through a gridview, after hitting the end of the view, a highlight color appears with intensity based on how far you keep dragging your finger. An my atrix, this color is a light blue.

I'm trying to remove this color but have been unsuccessful thus far. My minSDK is 2.2

To clarify, I'm not talking about the faded edges of the gridview or the individual items highlight color.

Comment: do you want to do that in your application or in your cellphone?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`setOverScrollMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29) method or the accompanying XML attribute, `android:overScrollMode`. You can set `android:overScrollMode="never"` on scrolling views in your layouts without having to call a method that did not exist before API 9 (Android 2.3).

Comment: Thanks, but I have to target 2.2, sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: Are you sure? That feature was introduced in 2.3. Maybe it's a custom rom or manufactor modification?

Comment: If you do this in a layout attribute previous versions of the platform will simply ignore it without incident. Just remember to build against the newer SDK and set minSdkVersion="8".